# how to fix getting undefined for model classes using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am learning to use sequelize with my Next.js app.I set up the sequelize, used the cli to generate migrations, created the model (user) , and when i try to test it, going to the http://localhost:3000/api/app . i get an error -> Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined.

my model class is coming up as undefined. anyone has any idea?

*director structure

```
MyApp
...
> database
 - db.js
> migrations
> models
 -user.js
> node_modules
> pages
  > api
     - app.js
```

db.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize('mydb', 'root', 'pass', {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorsAliases:false,
    logging: function () {},
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    },
    dialectOptions: {
        socketPath: "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
    },
    define: {
        paranoid: true
    }
});  

db.authenticate().then(() => {
       console.log('connection error');
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log('Connection successful');
    });

module.exports = db;
```

model/User.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const user = sequelize.define("User", {
        id : {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false, 
            autoIncrement:true,
            primaryKey:true
        },
        firstName : {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        }
        lastName : {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        created: {
          type: 'TIMESTAMP',
          defaultValue: DataTypes.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
          allowNull: false
        },
        updated:{
          type: 'TIMESTAMP',
              defaultValue: DataTypes.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
              allowNull: false
         }
    }); 
    return user;
};
```

pages/api/app.js

```
const models = require('../../models')

export default (req, res) => {
   models.user.findAll();          //error => Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You define uppercase `User` in the `User.js` file, so you have to use it uppercase:

```
const models = require('../../models');

export default async (req, res) => {
  const users = await models.User.findAll();
  console.log(users);
};
```

Comment: I think the main problem is in the Sequelize code, because it's not recognizing the `user` in models, that's why it returns `undefined` when you try to call the `findAll()` function, I thought uppercase `User` will help.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas - I uninstalled/installed, added the files again still get the same undefined error. if you think of anything else , on to debug or test this let me know. thank you in advance

Comment: also running into this, any follow up?